# How to implement RSA public key cryptosystem in python

Tags: python, rsa

I need big help with an exercise I'm struggling with... here is what I have to do:
Implementation of the RSA public key cryptosystem (n,e,d).   [I need to say that I'm programming in python for a couple of months so I'm still a newbie]

1)first Proceed with Key generation
•Generation of two big prime numbers p and q for the factorization of n using the Miller Robin property.
•Choice of e and computation of d using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

2)Encryption and decryption
•using exponentiation of plain/ciphertext

Here is the RSA which I got, searching also on the web and trying to adapt to my necessities.
I'd appreciate it if anyone knows how to solve it as I tried a lot of times to adjust but I'm stuck at a point in which I don't know what else to do.

```
import random
import math

message = int(input("Enter the message to be encrypted: "))

def RabinMillerWitness(test,possible):
    a,b,n=long(test%possible),possible-1,possible
    if a==1:
        return False
    A=a
    t=1
    while t<=b:
        t<<=1
    t>>=2
    while t:
        A=pow(A,2,n)
        if t&b:
            A=(A*a)%n
        if A==1:
            return False
        t>>=1
    return True

smallprimes = (3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,
                47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97)

def getPrime(b,seed):
    #Generates an integer of b bits that is probably prime
    bits=int(b)
    assert 64<=bits
    k=bits<<1
    possible=seed|1 
    good=0
    while not good:
        possible+=2 
        good=1
        for i in smallprimes:
            if possible%i==0:
                good=0
                break
        else:
            for i in xrange(k):
                test=random.randrange(2,possible)|1
                if RabinMillerWitness(test,possible):
                    good=0
                    break
    return possible

def egcd(a,b):
    # Extended Euclidean Algorithm
    u, u1 = 1, 0
    v, v1 = 0, 1
    while b:
        q = a // b
        u, u1 = u1, u - q * u1
        v, v1 = v1, v - q * v1
        a, b = b, a - q * b
    return u, v, a


def modInverse(e,n):
    return egcd(e,n)[0]%n

def totient(p,q):
    return (p-1)*(q-1)


def crypt(string,power,n):
    data1=0
    for char in string:
        data1<<=8
        data1+=ord(char)
    data2=pow(data1,power,n)
    ret=""
    while data2:
        data2,r=divmod(data2,256)
        ret=chr(r)+ret
    return ret

def encrypt(me):
    en = math.pow(me,e)
    c = en % n
    print("Encrypted Message is: ", c)
    return c
 
print("Original Message is: ", message)
c = encrypt(message)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when you ask specific technical questions. Are you seeing an error that you don't understand? Or is your code behaving in unexpected ways? Please be explicit about the the problem for which you would like our help.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Thanks for your answers! c: Basically the first problem is that it says in the function encrypt is not declared, idk how to recall it from the previous methods. Also I think some other problems will pop up after that I'll fix this one